# mySQL query retrieves data differently in same condition

Tags: javascript, mysql, for-loop, socket.io

I am have made a chat application in Node-JS and Socket.io with MySQL database. I am done with everything but got stuck in one thing, that I cannot solve. When a user login to their account, they are redirected to their inbox and then the list of user he chatted with are displayed. For example the current user who logged in is `John` and he chatted with a person name `Doe` when `John` clicks the `Doe` name from the list to open the chats, at that time all the messages are retrieved from the database. The data is stored as `Array of Objects` in a variable `data`. What I did in the code that, I have looped through this `data` and appended each message to the chat box. Where all the messages displays. There are two categories in each message `Message To` and `Message From`. These categories are because to distinguish that who texted whom. And then I change the `background color` of these messages. The messages sent from my side will have background `Grey` and the person messaged me will have `Blue` background.

Now the basic problem I faced is, when the length of `From Messages` or `To Messages` are less than **13** then the chat is displayed in a sequence and each of the messages are on the right place. But when the length of any of the above messages exceeds **13** then what happens is, The messages I have sent are displayed first, and then the user who sent me the messages are displayed.

**Messages from and Messages to have length less than 13 so its fine now**

[image]

**When it exceeds the length 13 then here first my messages are shown**

[image]

**And then the user sent to me are shown**

[image]

**The data format**

[image]

**The Script Displaying the chat**

```js
var ac_user = data.active_user;
socket.on("get_ret_messages",(data)=>{
       while (chatBody.hasChildNodes()) { chatBody.removeChild(chatBody.firstChild); }

       for(let i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
             if(data[i].mess_to == ac_user){
                 mess = '<div class="bubble you">'+data[i].mess_txt+'<br><span class="time">'+data[i].mess_time+'</span></div>';
                   chatBody.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",mess);
                }
                else{
                  mess = '<div class="bubble me">'+data[i].mess_txt+'<br><span class="time">'+data[i].mess_time+'</span></div>';
                 chatBody.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",mess);
             }
           }

           chatBody.scrollTop = chatBody.scrollHeight;

          });
```

**The Query**

```js
socket.on("get_user_messages",(data)=>{
      var GET_CLICKED_USER_MESS = "SELECT mess_txt,mess_time,mess_to FROM (select mess_to as user_id,mess_txt,mess_time,mess_id,mess_to from messages where mess_from = '"+data.active+"' AND mess_to='"+data.clicked+"' UNION select mess_to as user_id,mess_txt,mess_time,mess_id,mess_to from messages where mess_from = '"+data.clicked+"' AND mess_to='"+data.active+"' ORDER BY mess_id ASC) sq join users on users.id = sq.user_id";
          con.query(GET_CLICKED_USER_MESS,(err,res)=>{
             if(err) throw err;
             socket.emit("get_ret_messages",res);
          })
       });
```

> I am quite sure that the problem can be in the query, but I don't know what is that.

Comment: what does mess_to = 1 and mess_to = 2 mean?

Comment: i doubt it is this loop, it is pretty simple and has no reason to fail (except maybe if `insertAdjacentHTML` were async and took various time to execute, but that's not the case afiak, and it wouldn't be perfectly ordered by user). My guess is that it comes from the query that sends data, maybe sql optimizes it differently when messages are more than 13 chars?

Comment: @lone_worrior these are the ids to detect which user the message is destinated to, apparently

Comment: @lone_worrior mess_to and mess_from are the two columns which are foreingn keys which references the user_id . 1,2,3... are the ids of individual users

Comment: i also note that in your logs, the `mess_time` property is not always formatted in the same way, is it normal?

Comment: @Kaddath its not about exceeding 13 characters, its about exceeding the length of the mess_from and mess_to. For example a user sent more than 13 messages or received more than 13 messages then the problem occurs

Comment: @Kaddath yes, this is just I was formatting the date , so its just I was testing, I have made it perfect in last

Comment: Ok i see, if the "from" and "to" messages are retreived by separate query, can you add the script that assembles them? And if not and retreived by a single query, share the query?

Comment: so data you posted contains only mess_to..where is mess_from coming from ?

Comment: @Kaddath see the query I have updated

Comment: shouldn't the ORDER BY be on the `mess_time` rather than id? or is it ordered afterwards? I was told recently that SQL can optimize differently the query based on number of data, for operators like UNION

Comment: Can you publish result of `console.log(data)` before `for loop`?

Comment: @artg it is before the for loop, which I have published

Comment: @Kaddath still showing the same order, but this time the messages I have sent came first

Comment: @Kaddath, I got now that the problem is in the query, can you find out at why its behaving differently

Comment: what is the sql type of your `mess_time` column?

Comment: anyway try to move the ORDER BY at the end of the query, we'll see about the type if it fails: `"SELECT mess_txt,mess_time,mess_to FROM (select mess_to as user_id,mess_txt,mess_time,mess_id,mess_to from messages where mess_from = '"+data.active+"' AND mess_to='"+data.clicked+"' UNION select mess_to as user_id,mess_txt,mess_time,mess_id,mess_to from messages WHERE mess_from = '"+data.clicked+"' AND mess_to='"+data.active+"') sq join users on users.id = sq.user_id ORDER BY mess_time ASC"`

Comment: @Kaddath I am initializing that with a string, I get the data as new Date() and then get the time and convert them to toDateString();

Comment: Oh, it worked mate, @Kaddath please make your comment as answer so that I can mark it thank you so much !

Comment: ok then, i won't refuse this little reward ;)

Comment: Lol for sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the little explanation: the `ORDER BY` must be placed at the end for it to be effective, or else it will onlt order the sub-query, and the order was probably messed up by the `JOIN`

the query:

```
"SELECT mess_txt,mess_time,mess_to FROM (SELECT mess_to AS user_id,mess_txt,mess_time,mess_id,mess_to FROM messages WHERE mess_from = '"+data.active+"' AND mess_to='"+data.clicked+"' UNION SELECT mess_to as user_id,mess_txt,mess_time,mess_id,mess_to FROM messages WHERE mess_from = '"+data.clicked+"' AND mess_to='"+data.active+"') sq JOIN users ON users.id = sq.user_id ORDER BY mess_time ASC"
```